# How to replace android:inputType="none" in Code

Tags: android, xml-layout

I was expecting something like `editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NONE)`, but there is no such variable as TYPE_NONE. Can any body help me. It might be a simple question. I am using Android 2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use TYPE_NULL.

As per doc:
Set the type of the content with a constant as defined for inputType. This will take care of changing the key listener, by calling setKeyListener(KeyListener), to match the given content type. If the given content type is **TYPE_NULL** then a soft keyboard will not be displayed for this text view. Refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setInputType%28int%29).